# iOS Force Touch background on Locked Screen

Tags: ios

The new iOS and iPhone with Force Touch can have sort of animated background on the lock screen. I have been looking for a way to create my own background with this featurete, but my searching come up emty. Is it possible, or it is "Apple only" thing?

Comment: Apps don't have access to lock screen interactions/functionality, so it's an Apple-only thing

Answer (score 0):

You **can** create your own background with this feature, all you have to do is take a **live photo** *(iPhone 6s and 6s Plus for now)* and set it as your background.

Comment: It is not the same as the ones by Apple, where it reacts on the spot where you pushed.

Comment: It only does not taking the force for its speed